# Update pandas column with another dataframe without overriding existing

Tags: python, pandas

Been stuck on this the past hour, and couldn't find a thread here that applies..

Assuming a dataframe:

```
sample_id | value
0            NAN
1            NAN
2            NAN
3            NAN
...
19990        NAN
```

I have many other dataframe which are very small subsets of the above. eg:

```
sample_id | value
0            2
1            4
```

and

```
sample_id | value
194            2
200            4
```

How would I update the values in the first dataframe with the second dataframe but leaving everything else untouched? Using map() overrides the values so that subsequent updates remove previously written values..

Intended outcome:

df = df.(df2)
df = df.(df3)

final df:

```
sample_id | value
0            2
1            4
..            
194          2
200          4
..
19990        NAN
```

I know I can use loops, but I'm sure theres a faster solution thats on the brink on the horizon that I havent figured out..

Thank you! :)

Comment: [dataframe.copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) to make a copy of the first dataframe, and then operate on that when you want to change it? As you'd noticed, Pandas doesn't make copies unless it needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `combine_first`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample_id':pd.np.arange(0,10000),'value':pd.np.nan})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Sample_id':[3,4],'value':[2,4]})

df.set_index('Sample_id', inplace=True)

df1.set_index('Sample_id', inplace=True)

df_out = df1.combine_first(df)
print(df_out.head(10)
```

Output:

```
           value
Sample_id       
0            NaN
1            NaN
2            NaN
3            2.0
4            4.0
5            NaN
6            NaN
7            NaN
8            NaN
9            NaN
```

Comment: Do you have some null sample_ids?

Comment: no, sample_id is a column not the index column im afraid

Comment: You use set_index to get it into the index the use combine_first and reset_index afterwards.